# Turning non martingale into martingale by changing filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I would like to know if there is some theorem that allows us to turn a process $(X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ (under the canonical filtration) which is not a martingale into one, by maybe changing the filtration. In my particular case, I have some one dimensional process that has some trigonometric functions and a deterministic function of time.

More concretely, I have a process of the form $$X_t:=c(t) [\cos^{2/a} B_{f(t)} + \sin^{2/a} B_{f(t)}]$$

where $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a classical Brownian motion, and we can pick any $f(t)$ we like for our goal. I have checked that this is not a martingale using Ito's Lemma, for some functions $f(t)$ like $\log(t)$, $\sin(t), \cos(t)$, etc.

Comment: Hi, how do you apply Ito in this context ? If this is taking the deterministic time change as the df(X_t,t)/dt term then this is not there are article that tackle this issue but they are quite technical.

Comment: I partially disagree with the post below when it is said that you can't transform a process into a martingale by changing filtration, as long as "changing filtration" allows you to add some information to the initial filtration, even though I don't think this helps in this context though.

Comment: augmentation of filtration modifies the drift and there are formulas to do this, look for example at Protter's book where there is a chapter dedicated to this. The Brownian bridge (starting 0 and ending at 1) is an example where you start from a martingale to get a semimartingale (so the reverse case of yours). But if you have a drift from which you can extract a conditioning that eliminates the drift you might get what you want.

Comment: Dear @TheBridge what is the name of the book? I can't find a flaw on his argument, and the contrapositive of his claim tells us that indeed we can't obtain a martingale from a non martingale by a filtration change...

Comment: P. Protter : "Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations"

Comment: You can also have look at this book :  R. Mansuy,  M. Yor, "Random Times and Enlargements of Filtrations in a Brownian Setting" coll. « Lecture Notes in Mathematics »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the question in the title: this is not possible, since if $X$ is a martingale with respect to any filtration $\mathcal{G}$, then it is also a martingale with respect to its natural filtration. This is because if $X$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{G}$, in particular $X$ must be adapted with respect to $\mathcal{G}$ and hence $\mathcal{F}_t \subseteq \mathcal{G}_t$ for every $t \geq 0$. Therefore, by the tower property of conditional expectations it holds for $s \leq t$ that

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{G}_s] | \mathcal{F}_s]] = \mathbb{E}[X_s |\mathcal{F}_s] = X_s,$$
so $X$ is martingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}$. The answer to the question in the body is also negative, since the time-change of a martingale is again a (local) martingale, if we assume the time-change to be continuous. If we allow for general $f$, not necessarily increasing and continuous, the answer is also negative for your problem: Letting $a=1$ we have $\cos^2(B_{f(t)}) + \sin^2(B_{f(t)}) = 1$ and therefore $X_{t} = c(t)$ for any choice of $f$. Now if $c$ is not constant, no choice of $f$ will turn $X$ into a martingale.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With respect to your last statement though, I have my doubts. I mean, I see it is true for a monotically increasing function of time, but why in general for any $f$?

Comment: I see that we weren't using the same terminology. I usually assume tacitly that a time-change is continuous and increasing, in which case the preservation of the (local) martingale property is true. This doesn't apply for general $f$, however.